# How to make ViewModel to be initialized with build() that takes too long in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have 3 menus in my `Flutter` web: A, B, C.

And in menu B, it has sub menu 'week' and 'month'.

When I click menu 'month', It gets several data from `Firestore` and compile it and draw UI.

But the problem is that Firestore is very slow to get several data.

(Ofcouse, month data is bigger than week data, so It takes much more time)

So If It start getting data when I click sub-menu 'month', It's too long to wait for loading finished.

My Idea is to start getting data when I access menu A, which means my loading start point moves forward in order to shorten loading time from user's point.

`ViewModel` to extract month data is below:

```
class MonthRankingViewModel extends AsyncNotifier<List<UserModel?>> {
  late RankingRepository _rankingRepository;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  late DateTime firstDateOfMonth;
  late List<UserModel?> monthUserList;

  @override
  FutureOr<List<UserModel?>> build() async {
    _rankingRepository = RankingRepository();
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();

    firstDateOfMonth = DateTime(now.year, now.month, 1);
    firstDateOfMonth = DateTime(firstDateOfMonth.year, firstDateOfMonth.month,
        firstDateOfMonth.day, 0, 0);

    ref.watch(contractConfigProvider).when(
          data: (data) async {
            final String getUserContractType = data.contractType;
            final String getUserContractName = data.contractName;
            if (getUserContractType == "지역") {
              final userDataList = await ref
                  .watch(userRepo)
                  .getRegionUserData(getUserContractName);
              final monthUserList =
                  await updateUserScore(userDataList, "종합 점수");
              state = AsyncValue.data(monthUserList);
            } else if (getUserContractType == "기관") {
              final userDataList = await ref
                  .watch(userRepo)
                  .getCommunityUserData(getUserContractName);
              final monthUserList =
                  await updateUserScore(userDataList, "종합 점수");
              state = AsyncValue.data(monthUserList);
            } else if (getUserContractType == "마스터" ||
                getUserContractType == "전체") {
              final userDataList = await ref.watch(userRepo).getAllUserData();
              final monthUserList =
                  await updateUserScore(userDataList, "종합 점수");
              state = AsyncValue.data(monthUserList);
            }
          },
          error: (error, stackTrace) => print(error),
          loading: () {},
        );

    state = const AsyncValue.data([]);
    return [];
  }

  Future<List<UserModel?>> updateUserScore(
      List<UserModel?> users, String sortOrder) async {
    List<UserModel?> updateScoreList = [];
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();

    if (state.value!.isEmpty) {
      await Future.forEach(
        users,
        (user) async {
          final scoreUser = await calculateUserScore(user);
          updateScoreList.add(scoreUser);
        },
      );

      updateScoreList.sort((a, b) => b!.totalScore!.compareTo(a!.totalScore!));
      final indexList = ref
          .read(userProvider.notifier)
          .indexUserModel(sortOrder, updateScoreList);

      state = AsyncValue.data(indexList);
      return indexList;
    } else {
      return state.value!;
    }
  }

  Future<UserModel?> calculateUserScore(UserModel? user) async {
    final String userId = user!.userId;
    List<int> results;

    List<Future<int>> futures = [
      _rankingRepository.getUserStepScores(userId, firstDateOfMonth, now),
      _rankingRepository.getUserDiaryScores(userId, firstDateOfMonth, now),
      _rankingRepository.getUserCommentScores(userId, firstDateOfMonth, now),
    ];
    results = await Future.wait(futures);

    int userTotalScore = results[0] + results[1] + results[2];

    final updatedUser = user.copyWith(
      totalScore: userTotalScore,
      stepScore: results[0],
      diaryScore: results[1],
      commentScore: results[2],
    );
    return updatedUser;
  }
}

final monthRankingProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<MonthRankingViewModel, List<UserModel?>>(
  () => MonthRankingViewModel(),
);
```

And from screen A's `initState()` I call week and month viewmodels.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ref.read(weekRankingProvider);
    ref.read(monthRankingProvider);
  }
```

I works well with `week` data.

But error comes, when I tap 'month' sub-menu.

I guess, since `build` method of month viewModel takes long to finished, when I go menu B and tap 'month' it is not still finished.

So according to my setting, when tapping month, because I set If I tap week, It draws week data, and if tapping month, draws month data.

```
 void updateOrderPeriod(String value) async {
    setState(() {
      _sortOrderPeriod = value;
      loadingFinished = false;
    });
    switch (value) {
      case "이번달":
        List<UserModel?> monthList = await ref
            .read(monthRankingProvider.notifier)
            .updateUserScore(_userDataList, _sortOrderStandard);
        setState(() {
          _userDataList = monthList;
          loadingFinished = true;
        });
        break;
      case "이번주":
        setState(() {
          _sortOrderPeriod = "이번주";
        });
        List<UserModel?> weekList = await ref
            .read(weekRankingProvider.notifier)
            .updateUserScore(_userDataList, _sortOrderStandard);
        setState(() {
          _userDataList = weekList;
          loadingFinished = true;
        });
        break;
    }
  }
```

So even though build method is not finished,

`await ref.read(monthRankingProvider.notifier).updateUserScore(_userDataList, _sortOrderStandard)`

updateUserScore of this viewModel is ran again.

And It throws error since they crush.

I'm quite a newbie in Flutter, Please see my code and help me.